# how to bind the resultmap of mybatis to javafx combobox?

Tags: javafx-2, mybatis

I have existing java-mybatis application. I have created javafx scene with combobox.Combox shows list of values of ObservableList. I have modified DAO class to return ObservableList.
But its throwing runtime exception because mybatis returns a List.
**Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating interface javafx.collections.ObservableList with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javafx.collections.ObservableList.()**

I put below code to convert mybatis resultmap to ObservableList. JavaFX Combobox is populated with values.

```
Gates mapper = session.getMapper(Gates.class);
List<GateVO> gateVOs = mapper.getGates();
ObservableList<String> gates = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
if (gateVOs != null && !gateVOs.isEmpty()) {
    for (GateVO gateVO : gateVOs) {
        gates.add(gateVO.getGateNo());
    }
}
```

Can't we use mybatis results directly for binding javafx controls? 
Is there any alternate approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
ObservableList<GateVO> gates = FXCollections.observableArrayList(gateVOs);
```